# Create new variable (boolean) in r

Tags: r, variables, boolean

I need to create a new variable `LineItem_LongName` coded as 1 if the length of `LineItem` is greater than the mean, otherwise 0.

I have tried using the code:

```
data <- data %>% mutate(LineItem_LongName = ifelse(length(LineItem)) > mean(LineItem)),1,0))
```

but it gives me an error

```
Warning messages:
1: Problem with `mutate()` input `LineItem_LongName`.
i argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
i Input `LineItem_LongName` is `ifelse(length(LineItem) > mean(LineItem))`. 
2: In mean.default(LineItem) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

What should I do? Thank you!

Comment: 1. Is your column LineItem a string or numeric?
2. The condition for ifelse(condition,1,0) is not set correctly in the code above, there should not be so many brackets i.e. should be ifelse(len(LineItem) > mean(LineItem),1,0). Your condition is currently evaluating ifelse(length(LineItem)) which is not a boolean evaluation.

Comment: Hi Andy, I tried running the code: data <- data %>% mutate(LineItem_LongName = ifelse(len(LineItem) > mean(LineItem),1,0) but it did not work. It gave me an error. LineItem  is a character variable

Comment: Apologies for the len(LineItem) as there isn't a len function in R. My intention is to point out that the condition in your code is not written correctly as the brackets are not defined properly. Nonetheless, have added my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you want to compare with the `length` of `LineItem` or `LineItem` itself?

You can write with `ifelse` as :

```
library(dplyr)

data <- data %>% 
          mutate(LineItem_LongName = ifelse(LineItem > 
                  mean(LineItem, na.rm = TRUE),1,0))
```

However, you don't need `ifelse` and you can write :

```
data <- data %>% 
            mutate(LineItem_LongName = as.integer(LineItem > 
                   mean(LineItem, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

and in base R :

```
data$LineItem_LongName <- as.integer(data$LineItem > mean(data$LineItem, na.rm  = TRUE))
```

Comment: Hi, what would be the code if I needed to add na.rm =True because I can NA values. Thanks

Comment: Hi @ronak, apologies, I am new to this so thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there, just need better understanding of some of the functions.

- There is a `len` function in Python but not in R so you will get an error if you run `len(variable)` in R.
- To measure the number of characters of a string, you can use `nchar(str)` where `nchar("hello")` will return you 5.
- However, there is a function `length` in R, that is used to measure number of elements for a given vector. `length(c("hello","hello"))` will return 2.

I have created an example, try it and see if it is what you wanted. The mean is 5 so it is checking whether the length of colours is greater than 5.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame("Colours" = c("Red Red", "Red", "Green", "Green",NA), 
                 "Number" = c(1,2,3,4,5))

df
  Colours Number
1 Red Red      1
2     Red      2
3   Green      3
4   Green      4 
5    <NA>      5

df_new <- df %>% 
  mutate(LineItemLength = nchar(Colours)) %>% # Count number of characters including space
  mutate(LineItem_LongName = ifelse(LineItemLength > mean(LineItemLength,na.rm = T),1,0))

df_new
  Colours Number LineItemLength LineItem_LongName
1 Red Red      1              7                 1
2     Red      2              3                 0
3   Green      3              5                 0
4   Green      4              5                 0
5    <NA>      5             NA                NA

mean(df_new$LineItemLength,na.rm = T)
5 # Not 4
```